# Why do you trigger redraw on window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In project I'm working on right now many event callbacks end with the following line:

```
$(window).trigger('redraw');
```

What's the purpose of this method? When do you use it and why?

Comment: This will be triggering an event listener bound to the `window` that's listening for the custom `redraw` event. Search the code for something like `$(window).on('redraw', ... );`.

Comment: @sudharsan You can use anything as a custom event name, this might be the case if it's necessary to trigger it manually.